# Yii ActiveRecord - Is there way to update only dirty attributes?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, yii, process

In my application I have 2 processes which run almost at the same time and update same AR models.

I was facing the bug when it looked like some of this processes was not completed, but debugging them separately gave no errors.

Then I understood that the problem perhaps happens in the next case:

- Process A selects row X
- Process B selects row X
- Process B updates row X
- Process A updates row X

In the described case, process A will overwrite everything process B wrote.

Both B and A update different attributes.

Is there some way to avoid this overwriting? Is there some mechanism to make AR update only 'Dirty' attributes instead of all model attributes?

Please, do not explain me the solution without using AR. I understand it. But I would like to hear if there is some solution which will allow me do the required updates correctly still using AR.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you use AR's Transactions?

Comment: describe the processes please

Comment: @AliMasudianPour Of course each process uses transactions because both them do complicated jobs related with dialing with other webservices. But TR doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourTable::model()->updateByPk($id, array(
    'field1' => NewVal1,
    'field2' => NewVal2,
    'field3' => NewVal3
));
```

and make use of transactions:

```
$transaction=Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try
{
    //.... SQL executions OR model save()
    $transaction->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e) // an exception is raised if a query fails
{
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know what is transactions)) I like your idea very much.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how that will come along but here is a very **dangerous idea**  to do that , please read the [thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23729-how-to-write-locking-table-in-ar/)

- create another table for locking with respective model
- mylocks(object, object_type ,lock_type) , made it too generic
- e.g a record would be
- mylocks('post','table','write')

  `class Post extends ActiveRecord {

  ```
  public static $dirtyData=array();

  protected  $semaphore=false;

  //if its locked true, else false
  protected function hasSemaphore(){
      $c = new CDbCriteria;
      $c->compare('object',$this->getTableName());
      $c->compare('object_type','table');
      $lock=MyLocks::model()->find($criteria)
      return $lock!=null;
  }

  //
  public function setSemaphore(){
      if($this->semaphore==true)
         return true ;
      if($this->hasSemaphore()){
         Yii::app()->db->createCommand('LOCK TABLE '.$this->getTableName().' WRITE;')->execute();
        //insert a record to MyLocks 
        //insert into mylocks(object,object_type,lock_type) 
        //values ('post' ,'table','WRITE');
        $this->semaphore=true;
        return true;
      }
      $this->semaphore=false;
      return false;
  }

  protected function  mergeDirtyData(){
    //as I am holding write lock i should collect all dirty
    // data from other models to save it .... 
  }

  protected function releaseSemaphore(){
      if($this->semaphore){
        //delete matching from mylocks table  -- sorry I am lazy
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand('UNLOCK TABLES;')->execute();  
        $this->semaphore=false;
        $this->mergeDirtyData()
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

  ....

  public function beforeSave() {
      //if I am holding lock - release it   
      if(!$this->releaseSemaphore()){
        //probably someone else is holding 
        if($this->hasSemaphore())
            //set values to dirtyData 
            //self::dirtyData[]=array(attrA=>valueA,....);
            return false; // disable saving 
      }
      return parent::beforeSave();
  }
  ```

  }'

  so here will be your flow of operations

  //process A
  `$postA=Post::model();`

  ...

  `$postA->setSemaphore();`

  ... update some fields

  //process B

  `$postB=Post::model();`

  ... update some fields of $postB

  `$postB->update();`

  `$postA->update()`

**Other possible scenarios not handled**

- You will not be able to insert a record while there is a read lock by process one so you have
  to make come around that issue by , getting the lock release by Process B while inserting an 
  it resets that lock again(borrow it and give it back) sth like that
- I have not handled the dirtyData .The idea is only one model will correctly write the data to db
  which as set the semaphore ==lock

**Note**

Not production ready code , not tested so possibly with flaws

Comment: Nothing dangerous. At all. Just want to update different columns of same row. But AR native save() method updates all attributes.

Comment: what I meant was , my method is dangerous ;) Look at what I have written, it will give you idea how to handle that .Although its a rough idea